# Keyboard shortcut to copy from below in Excel (opposite of Ctrl+D)

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to copy a value from below a cell range to the cell range above it? Something opposite of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Say I have a value in A10 and I want to copy the value in A10 to the cells from A5:A9. Looking for a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there an opposite of <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>  fill down?

Not directly, however:

> you can fill up, but it's not a keyboard shortcut. In 2010, goto home, in the editing section (far right), second icon down on the left is fill.

Or:

> <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Source [Is there an opposite of the ctrl + d fill down](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/687025-there-opposite-ctrl-d-fill-down.html)

Or use the following macro:

> - Tools > Macro > Record New macro
> - Macro Name: FillUp, Short Cut: Ctrl+****+U (Because Ctrl+U is unavaliable)
> - Stop recording
> - Alt+F11, open the VBA Use the following code to overwrite the code in Modules, Sub FillUp()
>
>   ```
>   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
>   Selection.Copy
>   ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
>   ActiveSheet.Paste
>   Application.CutCopyMode = False
>   ```
> - Save

...

> how can I code it to work on multiple selected cells, like a row of data?

...

> I got it. Just changed 'ActiveCell' to 'Selection'

Source [Create shortcut for "Fill Up"](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/662150-create-shortcut-for-fill-up.html)